# Time upload part of bash script and output in MM:SS

Tags: bash, timer

I have a function which uploads a file to a server, I want to measure how long that part of the script takes and display the result for use un the output,
eg:

`echo "$file uploaded in XXXM:XXs"`

I can display the number of seconds, with:

```
my_upload_stuff here
echo "$file uploaded in $SECONDS"
```

Which as I understand displays the number of seconds since the script has started (which is fine for what I need) But this is as far as I can get.

Pulling my remaining hair out trying to figure this, seems to be way harder than I would imagine. Been all around the houses but nothing seems to work - I confess my bash skills are newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the command **time** if installed (but you'd have to use the external command **/usr/bin/time** and so you'd have to install it if it's not already installed ... because the built-in bash command **time** hasn't got the options to produce the desired output).

Or alternatively, you can perform the calculation explicitely, like that:

```
t1=$(date +%s)
<put upload_command here>
t2=$(date +%s)
echo "Time elapsed for upload: $(( ( t2 - t1 ) / 60 )) minutes and $(( ( t2 - t1 ) % 60 )) seconds"
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks so much! The second example worked a treat